# Process and send mouse event beneath the SVG element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am fairly new to javascript and front end world, and I would appreciate if anyone could help me to figure out how to send mouse event to the elements beneath the SVG element ?

This is the [reproducible snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/9chnub68/). 
Basically what I was trying to achieve is, if the mousewheel is scrolled on the circle, it should also invoke the mousewheel callback of the `div` element beneath it.
Currently it invokes only when mouse is scrolled on `div` element.

I searched a lot but couldn't find anything similar (Event Bubbling/capturing). 
Most of places they say to use "`pointer-events:none`" to disable events on svg, but I don't want this.

---

*Probably it has nothing to do with d3, but still I added for sake of completeness*

Comment: Why is pointer-events unsuitable?

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry maybe I don't know how to use `pointer-events`. When I tried `pointer-events:none` on SVG, it ignores SVG zooming like in my example and sends the event to div beneath. Like [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/gL8615sh/). Basically I want SVG to handle the event and then send it back to the layer event. I know the zooming is messed up, but it was just a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using D3 and for some reason don't want to use `pointer-events:none` on the SVG, you can just `d3.select("#your-div-id")` within the event for the SVG element. Then either pass that to a different function for handling the div mouse event or just do the manipulation within the SVG callback itself.

If you are trying to get zoom working like in your example, I suggest you check out something like this [geometric zooming example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999), or one of the many other examples for a better idea of the available methods.

Comment: When I tried `pointer-events:none` on SVG, it ignores SVG zooming like in my example and sends the event to div beneath. Like [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/gL8615sh/). Basically, I want SVG to handle the event and then send it back to the layer event. I know the zooming is messed up, but it was just a reproducible example. Thanks for the example link!